# Pull Last Closed Period From Text Values

Tags: vbscript, ibm-midrange

I'm using VBscript to pull data from an AS/400 iSeries. Although that's not technically important to the answer.

Currently, I search the pre-generated calendar and find the current period. Then I need to find the last closed period.

1 in 52.5 times, this is fine, I just take away 1. But every 52 or 53 weeks (depending on where the Tuesday lies) this will give me a value of 0, which doesn't work

Thing's I've tried:

- Go to today's date, take away one and use the updated period. This doesn't work because the 1st of every month will break the system
- If new period = 0, then 52. This doesm't work because as I said, it can easily be 53

Given's:

1. Last Closed Period is always the one before what we're on now
2. This script needs both period and year to run
3. period and year are always in a fixed place on a fixed screen
4. Let's say today is Period 23 Year 19. Last closed will be Period 22 Year 19.
5. If today was Period 01 Year 20. Last closed will be Period 52 Year 19. But...
6. If today was Period 01 Year 19. Last closed will be Period 53 Year 18.

Here's my code:

```
[PCOMM SCRIPT HEADER]
LANGUAGE=VBSCRIPT
DESCRIPTION=
[PCOMM SCRIPT SOURCE]
OPTION EXPLICIT

'Current Session'
autECLSession.SetConnectionByName(ThisSessionName)

'Declare'
DIM accNo 'KF account number
DIM RetPeriod, RetYear
DIM ScreenName
'End'

'Pull Screen Name (FMSOPS is the idea)'
ScreenName = autECLSession.autECLPS.GetText(1, 2, 6)
'End'

'Ask User for account number'
accNo = InputBox("Enter Account Number:","User Input","000000")
'End'


'Press F3 until main menu'
Do Until ScreenName = "FMSOPS"
    ScreenName = autECLSession.autECLPS.GetText(1, 2, 6) 'Pulls Calendar period
    autECLSession.autECLOIA.WaitForInputReady
    autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[pf3]" 'Back'
Loop
'End'


'Go to calendar'
autECLSession.autECLOIA.WaitForInputReady
autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "41"
autECLSession.autECLOIA.WaitForInputReady
autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[Enter]"
autECLSession.autECLOIA.WaitForInputReady
'End'

'Pulls period and year'
RetPeriod = autECLSession.autECLPS.GetText(10, 21, 2) 'Pulls Calendar period
RetYear = autECLSession.autECLPS.GetText(10, 28, 2) 'Pulls Calendar year
'End'

'If the period is 1, then go to last year'
'Else, go to last closed period'
If RetPeriod = "01" Then
    RetYear = RetYear - 1
    'Need to do 52/53 conversion here
Else
    RetPeriod = RetPeriod - 1 'Calendar period minus one
End If
'msgbox "You entered: " & RetPeriod 


'msgbox "You entered: " & accNo
```

Comment: If the platform doesn't matter, then it shouldn't be one of the tags (and doesn't even really need to be mentioned at all).

Comment: I did it so things like `autECLSession.autECLPS.GetText` are explained for answers. It's not something seen in VBScript usually, but the libraries that iSeries generates

Comment: Do you have a call that can retrieve the period for a given date?  Or a call that can find the last period of a given year?

Comment: Unfortunately not, all I can do is pull it from the screen for today